# Will a ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy ever throw a RejectedExecutionException?

Tags: java, threadpool, executor

Are there any circumstances under which a [ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy.html) will throw a [RejectedExecutionException](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/RejectedExecutionException.html)?

It seems to me that the policy itself is intended to prevent throwing these Exceptions. The API for its interface method, [RejectedExecutionHandler.rejectedExecution()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/RejectedExecutionHandler.html) claims that it may throw a `RejectedExecutionException`. The API for CallerRunsPolicy.rejectedExecution() does not.

**Summary:** Do I need to explicitly handle a `RejectedExecutionException` on `execute()` if I'm using a `CallerRunsPolicy`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you don't. ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy would never throw `RejectedExecutionException` unless you explicitly throw it under `Runnable#run`

Comment: That's my understanding, too. Have you found any API documentation that confirms this?

Comment: Also, the source for JDK6 backs you up. But I'd rather have the API tell me specifically. :) - I'll accept this answer, anyway.

Comment: No, I didn't find any API docs stating that, I've checked JDK 6 `ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy` sources. That's easy to understand no exception is thrown there.